# Different code in different build variant

Tags: android, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

I have two build variants in my app, one is an standard app edition and the second one is a customization app.

```
productFlavors {
        customConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            applicationId 'es.com.custom'
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 3
            versionName '3.0.0'
        }
        standard {
            minSdkVersion 14
            applicationId 'es.com.standard'
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 3
            versionName '3.0.0'
        }
```

For the customization I have to implement new features, but just for the customization, so those new features will be not available on the standard version. I am not sure what i have to do.

1.- Two classes , one with the standard requirements and one with the custom requirements
2.- In the standard class do something like:

```
  if (getPackageName()==customConfig )
    // do the custom things
    else
    //do the standard things
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Build variants are the result of Gradle using a specific set of rules
>   to combine settings, code, and resources configured in your build
>   types and product flavors. Although you do not configure build
>   variants directly, you do configure the build types and product
>   flavors that form them.

```
 if(BuildConfig.Flavor.equals("customConfig")) 
    {

    }
  else
   {

   }
```

Read **[Building multiple flavors of an Android](http://www.androidauthority.com/building-multiple-flavors-android-app-706436/)**

Answer (score 2):

You must create source directories for each flavor.
So you will be able to maintain a separate file for the specific flavor.

Please go through the **[link](https://objectpartners.com/2015/03/31/using-android-product-flavors-to-build-full-and-demo-version-of-the-app/)**  that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one simple way. You should have a folder named "**standard**" right now in your project. Just create another folder named "**customConfig**" (Or it might have been created once the gradle synchronizes) in the same folder where the "**standard**" folder is.

In your "**customConfig**" create another folder called "res" (Again you might have it already). Then create another folder "values". In "values" folder you can create your value file. Name the file '**values.xml**' and return back to your project. You "**values.xml**" file should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <string name="custom_app_id">es.com.custom</string>s
</resources>
```

Now in your code you can check which variable environment you are in:

```
 if (getPackageName().equals(getString(R.string.custom_app_id)))// for custom
// do the custom things
else
//do the standard things
```

Hope this help!